# Значение __name__ и @app.route во Flask, Python

Tags: python, flask, route

Здравствуйте, изучая книгу по Python, наткнулся на такой код:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello() -> str:
   return 'Hello world from Flask'

app.run()
```

Здесь (в книге) указано, что "классу Flask нужно знать текущее значение **name**, когда создаётся новый объект Flask, поэтому оно должно быть передано в аргументе, что мы и сделали" - вообще не понял, зачем это нужно.

Ну и соответственно, как работает route я тоже не понял. Объясните, пожалуйста, максимально доходчиво.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**name** это специальная переменная(атрибут модуля) в которую сохраняется имя модуля. Просто о модулях -  https://wombat.org.ua/AByteOfPython/modules.html
@function - это декоратор. Грубо говоря декоратор это функция которая изменяет поведение другой функции, в гугле очень много инфы по поводу декораторов,  поэтому примеры писать не буду. В текущем примере @app.route обрабатывает функцию hello() перед ее исполнением `@app.route
def hello():
    pass`
является тем же что и `hello_new = app.route(hello) # hello_new - это измененная функция hello()`. Касаясь самого фласка, app.route обрабатывает функцию hello как адрес(ссылку) на функцию представления нашего приложения. То есть чтобы при запуске нашего приложения увидеть 'Hello world from Flask', нам нужно обратится к функции hello, которая вернет нам эту строку, а функция вызывается с помощью указания ее имени как пути к странице приложения. http:\app_host:app_port\hello.